# Alias\symbolic link icons

Tags: finder, macos, symlink, alias

I installed Mavericks on an external SSD drive and now want to point my music, pictures and video to ones on my previous drive.
I created a link using `ln` command, a link was created. I launched iTunes, it correctly determined the working directory and was able to play my music. BUT in Finder the icon of iTunes directory (~/Music/iTunes) was like a blank document with an arrow while original folder has a customised icon. Also I tried creating an alias for that folder - and icon became just a regular folder icon. What is it?

Comment: Wow this happens only if I name target symlink as "iTunes"! I've created another link to that "external" iTunes folder and named it "sample" - and now Finder shows me the right icon!
Moreover, I deleted "~\Music\iTunes" symlink and renamed that "sample" symlink to "iTunes" - and I got my icon! But again not full success - when I changed icon of original folder, symlink icon didn't reflected that.

Comment: Tip : on Mac, the separator in paths is `/`.

Comment: @NicolasBarbulesco oh yes, I mistyped it here (but in terminal I wrote with `/`)

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here. I used Onyx Maintenance, then Rebuild tab and that fixed the icons. As a side-effect, it cleared custom icon positions, and other Finder display parameters etc.

Answer (score 0):

It's bug from apple os x since 10.9 came out finder doesn't update the icons of symlinks when the original folder/file icon changed.

go to the Apple site and fill a bug report, please.